# Searching files in sftp location based on some Regex using JSch library

Tags: java, regex

I have 3 kinds of files present in an sftp location given as below:

1. `UploadBusinessLicense_xyzbus_<somerandomnumber>.jpg`
2. `GovernmentPhotoID_xyzgovern_<somerandomnumber>.jpg`
3. `CustomerConsentForm_xyzconsent_<somerandomnumber>.jpg`

I need to query the sftp directory to get the files which matches any of these patterns. What Regex pattern can I use for that?

i have tried with the following pattern 
**UploadBusinessLicense_* | GovernmentPhotoID_***
and its not working.i am new to regex .so any help would be appreciated

```
        String REGEX_PATTERN =
        "(UploadBusinessLicense|CustomerConsentForm|UploadBusinessLicense)_.*?_.*?\\.jpg";

        int SFTPPORT = 22;
        Session session = null;
        Channel channel = null;
        ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;
        List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> list = null;

        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        try {
            session = jsch.getSession("username", "host", 22);
            session.setPassword("password");
            java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.connect();

            channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
            channel.connect();

            channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
            channelSftp.cd("file directory");

            System.out.println("fetching files");

            list = channelSftp.ls(REGEX_PATTERN);

            for (ChannelSftp.LsEntry entry : list) {
                channelSftp.get(entry.getFilename(), "/home/tofankumarbal/Pictures");

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (channelSftp != null && channelSftp.isConnected()) {
                    channelSftp.exit();
                    session.disconnect();
                    channel.disconnect();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }

    }
```

after searching with the above regex  the Vector list is getting empty.

Comment: provide sample input/output and what you've tried so for.

Answer (score 0):

From the question, I understand that you want to match 3 kinds of strings with following criteria,

1. A string starting with UploadBusinessLicense, GovernmentPhotoID, and CustomerConsentForm.
2. Based on the kind of string it start the next set should be bus, govern and consent.
3. Followed by random set of numbers.
4. Ending with jpg extension.

   **String regex = "(UploadBusinessLicense_[a-zA-z]+bus|GovernmentPhotoID_[a-zA-Z]+govern|CustomerConsentForm_[a-zA-Z]+consent)_\d+\.jpg"**

Note : When using regex in Java use extra \

Example string I used are :

- UploadBusinessLicense_xyzbus_1234545452454.jpg
- GovernmentPhotoID_xyzgovern_12345.jpg
- CustomerConsentForm_xyzconsent_5456456.jpg

I hope this would solve you problem.

Comment: thanks  for your suggestion. but i wonder  this is also not working.  but when i search with  UploadBusinessLicense_*  it gives me all the  UploadBusinessLicense  files . is there some kind of restriction in the jsch library  regarding file search patterns